# Merge two dataframes and add a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Having a couple of dataframes like that (df, df2),

```
df
    D  R1  R2  R3
0  D1   1   1   1
1  D1   1   1   1
2  D2   1   2   1
3  D2   1   2   1
4  D3   1   0   1

df2
    D  R1  R2  R3
0  D1   1   1   1
1  D1   1   1   1
2  D2   1   3   1
3  D2   1   3   1
4  D3   1   1   1
5  D3   2   2   2
6  D3   2   2   2
```

Is it possible to merge them and create an additional column called "new_values" with those values that only exist in one of the two dataframes ?

Expected result :

```
     D  R1  R2  R3      _merge   new_values
0   D1   1   1   1        both   False
1   D1   1   1   1        both   False
2   D1   1   1   1        both   False
3   D1   1   1   1        both   False
4   D2   1   2   1   left_only   False
5   D2   1   2   1   left_only   False
6   D3   1   0   1   left_only   False 
7   D2   1   3   1  right_only   False
8   D2   1   3   1  right_only   False
9   D3   1   1   1  right_only   False
10  D3   2   2   2  right_only   True
11  D3   2   2   2  right_only   True
```

Comment: Why are only last 2 rows True?

Comment: Because index 5 and 6 (df2) doesn't exists in df , from index 0 to 4 can be both, right_only or left_only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use outer join with `merge` and test memebrship of indices in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df = (df.reset_index()
        .merge(df2.reset_index(), 
               how='outer', 
               indicator=True, 
               on=df.columns.tolist()))

df['new_values'] = ~df.pop('index_y').isin(df.pop('index_x'))
print (df)
     D  R1  R2  R3      _merge  new_values
0   D1   1   1   1        both       False
1   D1   1   1   1        both       False
2   D1   1   1   1        both       False
3   D1   1   1   1        both       False
4   D2   1   2   1   left_only       False
5   D2   1   2   1   left_only       False
6   D3   1   0   1   left_only       False
7   D2   1   3   1  right_only       False
8   D2   1   3   1  right_only       False
9   D3   1   1   1  right_only       False
10  D3   2   2   2  right_only        True
11  D3   2   2   2  right_only        True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
df3 = (df.assign(new_values=~df.index.isin(df2.index))
         .merge(df2.assign(new_values=~df2.index.isin(df.index)),
                how='outer', indicator=True)
       )
```

output:

```
     D  R1  R2  R3  new_values      _merge
0   D1   1   1   1       False        both
1   D1   1   1   1       False        both
2   D1   1   1   1       False        both
3   D1   1   1   1       False        both
4   D2   1   2   1       False   left_only
5   D2   1   2   1       False   left_only
6   D3   1   0   1       False   left_only
7   D2   1   3   1       False  right_only
8   D2   1   3   1       False  right_only
9   D3   1   1   1       False  right_only
10  D3   2   2   2        True  right_only
11  D3   2   2   2        True  right_only
```