# merge two dataframes taking into account new rows in one of them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Having the following dataframes,

df1

```
   Device  name  Rev serial
0      D1  fpc0    1    xyz
1      D1  pic0    1    xxx
2      D2  fpc0    1    hij
3      D2  pic0    1   hijj
4      D3  fpc0    2    xyx
5      D3  pic0    1    xll
6      D3  fpc1    2    xhh
7      D4  fpc1    1    tll
8      D4  fpc2    1    xho
9      D4  pic0    1    lss
10     D5  fpc0    1    qqq
11     D5  pic0    1    xqz
```

df2

```
   Device  name  Rev serial
0      D1  fpc0    1    xyz
1      D1  pic0    1    xxx
2      D2  fpc0    1    hij
3      D2  pic0    1   xxxx
4      D3  fpc0    2    xij
5      D3  pic0    1    xll
6      D3  fpc1    2    xhh
7      D3  pic1    1    xtt
8      D4  fpc1    1    tll
9      D4  fpc2    1    xho
10     D4  pic0    1    lss
11     D4  pic1    2    xss
12     D5  fpc0    1    qqq
13     D5  pic0    1    xqz
14     D5  pic1    2    xpr
```

,in which a device can have the same number of rows in both dataframes or different ones, I don't know if it is possible to achieve the following in a simple way(i.e having a single index):

Expected output:

```
   Device  name  Rev serial      _merge   new_values
0      D1  fpc0    1    xyz        both   False
1      D1  pic0    1    xxx        both   False
2      D2  fpc0    1    hij        both   False
3      D2  pic0    1   hijj   left_only   False
4      D3  fpc0    2    xyx   left_only   False
5      D3  pic0    1    xll   left_only   False
6      D3  fpc1    2    xhh        both   False
7      D4  fpc1    1    tll        both   False
8      D4  fpc2    1    xho        both   False
9      D4  pic0    1    lss        both   False
10     D5  fpc0    1    qqq        both   False
11     D5  pic0    1    xqz        both   False
12     D2  pic0    1   xxxx  right_only   False
13     D3  fpc0    2    xij  right_only   False
14     D3  pic1    1    xll  right_only   False
15     D3  pic0    1    xtt  right_only   True
16     D4  pic1    2    xss  right_only   True
17     D5  pic1    2    xpr  right_only   True
```

new_values column means that this device in df2 has "new" entries:

For example:

in df1 we have :

```
4      D3  fpc0    2    xyx
5      D3  pic0    1    xll
6      D3  fpc1    2    xhh
```

in df2 we have:

```
4      D3  fpc0    2    xij
5      D3  pic0    1    xll
6      D3  fpc1    2    xhh
7      D3  pic0    1    xtt <--- this row is new for this device
```

Basically we can have 2 cases:

Case 1

One device (D1,D2, etc...) can have the same number of rows in both dataframes (elements can be equal or different):

D1 and D2 (in that case all rows are equals)

df1

```
0      D1  fpc0    1    xyz   
1      D1  pic0    1    xxx   
2      D2  fpc0    1    hij   
3      D2  pic0    1   xxxx
```

df2

```
0      D1  fpc0    1    xyz  
1      D1  pic0    1    xxx  
2      D2  fpc0    1    hij  
3      D2  pic0    1   xxxx
```

Case 2

One device can have X rows in one dataframe and X+y in the other (elements can be equal or different):

df1

```
5      D3  pic0    1    xll
6      D3  fpc1    2    xhh
7      D4  fpc1    1    tll
8      D4  fpc2    1    xho
9      D4  pic0    1    lss
10     D5  fpc0    1    qqq
11     D5  pic0    1    xqz
```

df2

```
4      D3  fpc0   2    xij
5      D3  pic1    1    xll
6      D3  fpc1    2    xhh
7      D3  pic0    1    xtt
8      D4  fpc1    1    tll
9      D4  fpc1    1    xho
10     D4  pic0    1    lss
11     D4  pic1    2    xss
12     D5  fpc0    1    qqq
13     D5  pic0    1    xqz
14     D5  pic1    2    xpr
```

In that case indexes 6 and 7 from df2 are "new" for D3, index 11 is "new" for D4 and index 14 is "new" for D5.

I did a very similar questions here:

[Merge two dataframes and add a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71393079/merge-two-dataframes-and-add-a-new-column)

but I didn't take some things into account.

Thanks.

Comment: The logic for `new_values` is not particularly clear. Can you update the question to add some more explanation with help of examples?

Comment: updated, hope it's more clear now. Thanks

Comment: Does it matter if the values are not the same for other columns?

Comment: Values can be equal or different , i.e in df1 you can have D1 fpc 1 xyz and in df2 you can have D1 fpc 2 rrr for example.

Comment: So the common columns are `Device` and `name`?

Comment: Yes, they are common columns

Comment: I've updated the data , to be more realistic. name now is fpcx or picx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the following approach, but I'm not sure if it's optimal

```
df1['_common_1'] = df1['Device'] + df1['name']
df1['_common_2'] = df1['Device'] + df2['name']

final_df = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer',indicator=True)

final_df['new_values'] = ~final_df.pop('_common_2').isin(final_df.pop('_common_1'))

   Device  name  Rev serial      _merge  new_values
0      D1  fpc0    1    xyz        both       False
1      D1  pic0    1    xxx        both       False
2      D2  fpc0    1    hij        both       False
3      D2  pic0    1   hijj   left_only       False
4      D3  fpc0    2    xyx   left_only       False
5      D3  pic0    1    xll        both       False
6      D3  fpc1    2    xhh        both       False
7      D4  fpc1    1    tll        both       False
8      D4  fpc2    1    xho        both       False
9      D4  pic0    1    lss        both       False
10     D5  fpc0    1    qqq        both       False
11     D5  pic0    1    xqz        both       False
12     D2  pic0    1   xxxx  right_only       False
13     D3  fpc0    2    xij  right_only       False
14     D3  pic1    1    xtt  right_only        True
15     D4  pic1    2    xss  right_only        True
16     D5  pic1    2    xpr  right_only        True
```